# Mysql one to many join, rows to columns

Tags: mysql, join, one-to-many

I have 2 tables in MySql database called **con01_objects** and **con01_object_contacts**. They have foreign key as shown in picture (con01_objects.id = con01_object_contacts.obj_id).

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ecMNN.jpg)

As you see, **con01_object_contacts** table contains **contact_type** column which will have several contact types for one object and their corresponding contact(contact types : 0-number, 1-web, 2-tolfree, 3- facebook, 4-twitter, 5-instagram, 6-youtube, 7- mail).

What I need is to join these 2 tables, so that there will be no repeated objects. I need a joined result which will show every contact type as one column. If there is no contact for a object in corresponding contact type, that entry should be NULL.

+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

objects---   contype_0(num)----     contype1(WEB) ----- contype(tolfree) 
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

obj1 ----    +96785445578700  ----  SOMETHING.c0M  ----- 45469889

obj2  ----   +55457875748787  ------  *NULL*    ---------------------      42499898

*I have tried this query but it returns repeated rows as one object has different contact types.* :

**SELECT * FROM con01_objects LEFT JOIN con01_object_contacts ON con01_objects.id= con01_object_contacts.obj_id**

Thanks beforehand.

Comment: `please click to see` ... in addition to not including necessary information, your link is barely clickable.  Please invest some more time into your question, and show us any query you have already tried.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen sorry, please see changes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for this:

```
Select distinct(a.jid), 
(SELECT contact FROM con01_object_contacts where contact_type = '0') as contype_0, 
(SELECT contact FROM con01_object_contacts where contact_type = '1') as contype_1,
(SELECT contact FROM con01_object_contacts where contact_type = '2') as contype_2
from con01_objects a
left join con01_object_contacts as b
on a.id = b.obj_id;
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, I changed your query a little bit and i got what I want.